# Get resources xml file from url in JAVA

Tags: java, android, xml

Currently I am storing my resources files on local directory and I am calling them by:

```
Resources res = getResources();
    final String[] docukrz = res.getStringArray(R.array.docukrz);
```

I wanted to move this online, so I have created a url: https://example/strings.xml

Now how I can get that file so I will call it from URL, not resources folder.

I am a total beginner and read a lot of different articles and tutorials but cannot pull that together. Sorry if that is a duplicate.

Comment: The ID's in R.class are generated at compile time as int's. So, technically this is not possible. Perhaps if you can explain why you want to get the strings from `Resources` and not just your own object, we can help.

Comment: I would like to use the file the same way I am using it from resources, but instead storing it online. That is a String file, so i want to create some arrays containing strings from that file.

Comment: Should I use this tutorial? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html All of it looks really complicated, and I thought this would be quite easy, but the more I read and ask the more questions I have. Maybe it is better to keep the xml file in my resources and just release a new version of the app whenever I will like to update it? It is just 1 simple file with strings.

Answer (score 3):

That is not how resources work. The resources framework is built around local storage, a specific set of directories and "qualifiers", and runtime determination of which resources should be available from the app.

You are welcome to download an xml file from the internet and parse it, but this will never be part of your app's resources.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. If I will parse it from URL, can I create a String Array from the URL? URL link leads to an xml file actually.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you use `Retrofit` and `Kripton` (I'm the author of this library) libraries to download an XML file from a URL and convert it into a Java object (or objects).

The [wiki page](https://github.com/xcesco/kripton/wiki/Persist-on-the-network-%28with-Retrofit%29) of Kripton tries to explain how to do: instead of use JSON parser, you need to use XMLParser:

```
// create retrofit using Kripton converter factory
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
  .baseUrl(“https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/")
  .addConverterFactory(KriptonBinderConverterFactory.create(BinderType.XML))
  .build();
JsonPlaceHolderService service = Retrofit.create(JsonPlaceHolderService.class);
// consume service
Response<List<Post>> response = service.getAllPost().execute();
```

More information about Retrofit and Kripton Persistence Library:

- [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)
- [Kripton Persistence Library](https://github.com/xcesco/kripton/wiki)

If you want to see a working example using Retrofit and Kripton Persistence Library, you can see my example app RSS Reader on [GitHub](https://github.com/xcesco/kripton-examples/tree/master/rss-reader).